# Qt failed to load color scheme

Tags: qt, colors

I tried to load new colorschemes in xml format from [here](https://github.com/alexpana/qt-creator-wombat-theme) and [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/44426/dusk-monokai-and-twilight-themes-for-qtcreator)
, so I copied the `xmls` to `~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/styles`, but when I go under `Tools->Options->Text Edito->Color Scheme` I get blank options under IntelliJ IDEA for each xml I added and when I choose one nothing changes. Also, when I try to change stylesheet with command

```
qtcreator -stylesheet=~/Downloads/stylesheet_1.css
```

I get

```
QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "~/Downloads/stylesheet_1.css" 
QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "~/Downloads/stylesheet_1.css" 
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Follow Symbol Under Cursor" under id 151
```

But the style changes nevertheless

I'm running Qt Creator 3.0.1(Qt 5.2.1) on Ubuntu 14.04LTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

Instead of

```
~/Downloads/stylesheet.css
```

Use absolute path

```
/home/username/Downloads/stylesheet.css
```

Cheers,

Comment: absolute and also relative path `../../Downloads/stylesheet.css` but without home dir `~`

Comment: For whatever reason, this does not work for me. I still get the parsing error.